# Extract the line in a file if the second column matches a certain value

Tags: awk, grep

I have a file and i want to print the entire line in a file if the second column matches a particular value in the file

My file contents are

```
    xxxxx-test|test|machine1
    xxxxx-test|abcc|machine2
    xxxxx-test|bcd|machine3
    xxxxx-test|efgh ijhk|machine4
    xxxxx-test|efgh ijhk2|machine4
```

now i want this line `xxxxx-test|efgh ijhk|machine4`
`grep` does not work efficiently here

```
cat file.txt | grep "efgh"
xxxxx-test|efgh ijhk|machine4
```

But when i `grep` for `test` it displays all the lines since my first column has `test` string in it.

```
cat file.txt | grep "test"
xxxxx-test|test|machine1
xxxxx-test|abcc|machine2
xxxxx-test|bcd|machine3
xxxxx-test|efgh ijhk|machine4
```

`awk` also does not seem to work.

```
 cat file.txt | awk -F'|' '$2=="test" '
xxxxx-test|test|machine1
```

This line gives nothing.

```
 cat file.txt | awk -F'|' '$2=="efgh"'
 cat file.txt | awk -F'|' '$2=="ijhk"'
```

When the value of string to match is `test` output should be `xxxxx-test|test|machine1`  .

When value of string to match is efgh, output should be `xxxxx-test|efgh ijhk|machine4`.

When value of string to match is ijhk, output should be `xxxxx-test|efgh ijhk|machine4`.

Any suggestions what other tools can i use?

Comment: Why don't you grep "|test" or "|test|"?

Comment: `grep` is line oriented, it can much multiple strings in the same line. Why don't you just try `grep '.*test.*efgh.*'`

Comment: What should be output if your input is `xxxxx-test|test|machine1<newline>xxxxx-test|t.*t|machine` and the string to match is `t.*t`? I'm asking if the "**string** to match" really is a literal string or if it's a regular expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `x=whatIwanttomatch`, e.g. `x=efgh`, If we want to stick with `grep`:

```
grep "^[^|]*|[^|]*$x" bla
```

The regular expression matches start of line, then gobbles everything that is not a "|", then one "|", then what you looked for before the next "|".

Using `awk`:

```
awk -v x="$x" -F'|' '$2 ~ x' bla
```

If the second column matches `efgh*` (starts with efgh) then we print.

No need to `cat` into a pipe, just send the file as an argument in both cases. Finally, in pure Bash:

```
while IFS=\| read -r col1 col2 col3; do 
    if [[ $col2 =~ *$x* ]]; then echo "$col1|$col2|$col3"; fi  ; 
done < bla
```

Again, we want the second column to start with our match.

**Addendum**

To make sure the match is a "word" in the second column, you need to surround the corresponding match with something marking "not a digit or letter" - in awk that can be `"([^0-9a-zA-Z]|^)"x"([^0-9a-zA-Z]|$)"` where we also have to allow for start of string `^` before and end of string `$` after. For `grep` that would be `[^[:alnum:]]` around the `$x`. For Bash you would need an `if` for the 4 exact cases (preceding and succeeding "|" or " ").

Comment: what if in the next run i have to match 'ijhk'. grep "^[^|]*|ijhk" bla does not work for that

Comment: edited, this grep "^[^|]*|$x" bla still does not work for where x=ijhk, grep "^[^|]*|ijhk" file.txt gives nothing.

Comment: @kanbus, sure..thank you, both the solutions works perfectly fine.  :)

Comment: Don't enclose scripts or strings in double quotes as that exposes the whole script/string to the shell for interpretation which means you then need to add backslashes to escape shell metachars. Also `.*foo.*` is exactly the same as `foo` when just matching a regexp, not storing/using the matching string. The correct syntax for the awk script you wrote would be `awk -v x="$x" -F'|' '$2 ~ x' bla` but see [@oguszismail answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55805803/1745001) for how to do this robustly so x gets treated literally even if it contains RE metachars.

Comment: Also see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/133219 if you're considering using a shell loop for this.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for improving the post, edited in.

Comment: @kabanus, the edited answer does not do the exact pattern matching, if there is a line having value ijhk2, then the awk solution matches both the line containing ijhk and ihjk2, rather than only matching line containing ijhk2.

Comment: @prex None of the solutions did (including other answers), you changed/specified the question again retrospectively. I will edit to include a "word" match, but please ask a new question if you have additional constraints.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need regular expressions for matching literal strings.

```
$ awk -F'|' -v m='efgh' 'index($2,m)' file
xxxxx-test|efgh ijhk|machine4
```

Answer (score 0):

tried on gnu awk

```
awk -F\| '$2~/^(test|abcc|bcd)$|^efgh|ijhk$/ {print}' file.txt
```